# Compare two effect sizes

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I want to ask whether two effect sizes (B1 and B2) are different than one another. Both B1 and B2 are derived from a Spearman correlation, and I can extract the SE and confidence intervals.

I understand that I could bootstrap and get new estimated distributions of B1 and B2, but is there a way to do this comparison using just the effect size estimates and SEs/CIs?

Comment: How does bootstrap not use the data you already have?

Comment: Sorry my phrasing was poor. I do have the data I would need to bootstrap, but is there a way to test B1 vs B2 without doing so (i.e. based on the SEs or CIs)?

Comment: I now see that you tagged this with [tag:regression] and [tag:regression-coefficients]. What are you doing?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking? To be honest, I am very unfamiliar with this community and it's norms/categories so if you can think of a better fit for the question I would be happy to change the tags

Comment: You picked those tags, so you see this question as having something to do regression. What are you doing that has you thinking that this is about regression?

Comment: I'm thinking that this is about how to compare two regression effect sizes with one another

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-overlapping-confidence-intervals-mean-nothing-about-statistical-significance-48360559900a

Comment: Bootstrapping seems to be a good way to go here. Notes:  1. You will want to bootstrap the difference of the correlations and construct a confidence interval. 2.  You will need to bootstrap in such a way so as to correctly capture the dependence structure  (impossible to know without more details of the experiment).   3.  Given that you are using rank-based statistics, it may be reasonable to use a smoothed bootstrap to avoid inducing more ties than expected.